# InfoPath 2013 cutting field in half when printing

Tags: infopath, printing

I'm not sure if this is the place to ask this particular question, but since there are other InfoPath questions I'll go ahead and ask.

I have a huge form with tons of show/hide formatting rules. When my form is expanded to like 5 or 6 pages, some of the fields that are now visible will be cut off on a page break... right in the middle through the text that was input.

Is there a way around this?